# Wordpress textbox input -> python -> display output on wordpress

Tags: php, python, wordpress

I have a python script I would like to use on my Wordpress website. The script takes a string input, manipulates the strings, and yields a list of strings as output. I would like to have a simple text box on my wordpress site, in which users can input text as the input to the python script, have the python script run, and display the output on the wordpress page.

After looking around the only suggestion I found was python-wordpress-xmlrpc, but I can't seem to make any sense out of it. Is there an easy way to do this, or a tutorial somewhere? I don't know php well, so translating the python to php is not an option.

Is there a way to modify this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress to take a textbox input?

Comment: I know you said it, but I **strongly** suggest you just to port the code to either php or javascript.

Comment: probably get it translated for a handful of pesos on one of the freelancing sites.

Comment: by 'port' do you mean translate it myself, or is there a way to have php read it?

Comment: is there a way to modify [link] (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress) to just take a textbox input?